# How to sync Realm data between iOS devices

Tags: swift, realm, cloudkit

I currently have an iOS app that uses Realm as its local database. Everything is working fine but what I would like to do is, be able to sync the data between iOS devices, I know I could use the Realm Cloud Platform services but right now I don't have enough revenue to justify the expenses for the service.

What are my free options to be able to sync the data between iOS devices?

Is CloudKit an option? If yes, would that play well with Realm or will I run into syncing issues etc.?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'll preface this answer by stating that nothing is absolute so this is just some general points.

Generally speaking, the databases don't 'work' with each other without integrating an additional API and writing the code to make that happen.

Realm Cloud offers seamless integration so that's what I would suggest - with low volume the pricing shouldn't be too bad. Also, with the upcoming integration with MongoDB, it's going to provide quite a bit of flexibility.

Firebase offers a free plan but it's a totally different kind of database (NoSQL) with a different API. That would require a massive re-write and total re-thinking of your data.

CloudKit works with CoreData, which is again a different database (well, a framework to a variety of back end storage solutions) and API. CD is 'more like' Realm but again, will still require a pretty big re-write. CloudKit exposes a [JS API](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/cloudkitjs) so you may be able to leverage that if you want to integrate JS/Web app.

Comment: Can you please clarify something for me? You mentioned that... CloudKit works with Core Date. Is Core Data required in order to use CloudKit? In other words is Cord Data the database language for querying CloudKit records? I was under the impression that these two were totally independent from each other.

Comment: Sure - *works with CoreData* simply meant that the two work well together but they are independent of each other. The important point is that either would would require additional API's and you would have to add additional code to take a Realm object (for example) and store it using CloudKit (or CoreData) and much of that is redundant - Realm provides both local and cloud storage with no additional API's or other code.

Comment: Thank you for the clarification. As I said, I would love to be able to use Realm Cloud Services but I currently cannot justify the $30 dollars a month.

Comment: How about this solution? https://github.com/caiyue1993/IceCream